# Is there a way to extract initials from macro containing a name with latex?

Tags: latex

I am writing a cv class, and want to extract the cvauthor initials. I have declare a macro in a .cls file that should contains the author name, after getting it, i want to split it according to a certain separator and gets the first letters of each sub-string. Here is what I did, but still getting  an error message.

myclass.cls

```latex
\ProvidesClass{resumecv}[2020/09/12 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}

\sodef\myspace{}{.1em}{0.5em plus0.5em}{2em plus.1em minus.1em} % User-defined letter spacing
\newcommand{\cvauthor}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvauthor}{\textsc{\myspace{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\FirstInitial}{}
\newcommand{\SecondInitial}{}
\newcommand*{\ExtractInitials}[1]{%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\FirstInit]%
    \StrChar{\FirstInit}{1}[\FirstInit]
    \renewcommand{\FirstInitial}{\FirstInit}
    \StrBehind{#1}{ }[\second]%
    \StrRemoveBraces{\second}[\SecondInit]%
    \StrChar{\SecondInit}{1}[\SecondInitial]
}

\newcommand*{\makeskeleton}{
     \begin{textblock}{20}(0,0)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvauthor}{}}{}{
                %\Huge\textcolor{darkYellow}{\textbf{\cvauthor}}
                % \renewcommand{\name}{\cvauthor}
                % \name
                \ExtractInitials{\cvauthor}
                \FirstInitial
                \SecondInitial
            }
    \end{textblock}
}
```

my-resume.tex

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{myclass}

\cvauthor{John Smith}  %%% whant to extract J and S
\begin{document}
    \makeskeleton
\end{document}
```

Error

```latex
! Use of \TP@textblock doesn't match its definition.
\text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                    #1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@...
l.5     \makeskeleton
                     
?
```

Need somebody's help.

Comment: \ProvidesClass{resumecv}[2020/09/12 CV class]  make a mistake a here it is

Comment: it is \ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/09/12 CV class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ifthen` package is missing
- `\ExtractInitials` fails  because `\cvauthor` saves the name with all the formatting like small caps etc. An easy workaround is to define a macro that just saves the plain name
- please keep in mind that your `\ExtractInitials` will fail in many cases: more than two name parts, names with prefix etc. Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at biblatex which is very good at parsing all kinds of names

---

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/09/12 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\sodef\myspace{}{.1em}{0.5em plus0.5em}{2em plus.1em minus.1em} % User-defined letter spacing
\newcommand{\cvauthor}[1]{\newcommand{\mycvauthor}{#1}\renewcommand{\cvauthor}{\textsc{\myspace{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\FirstInitial}{}
\newcommand{\SecondInitial}{}
\newcommand*{\ExtractInitials}[1]{%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\FirstInit]%
    \StrChar{\FirstInit}{1}[\FirstInit]
    \renewcommand{\FirstInitial}{\FirstInit}
    \StrBehind{#1}{ }[\second]%
    \StrRemoveBraces{\second}[\SecondInit]%
    \StrChar{\SecondInit}{1}[\SecondInitial]
}

\newcommand*{\makeskeleton}{
     \begin{textblock}{20}(0,0)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvauthor}{}}{}{
                %\Huge\textcolor{darkYellow}{\textbf{\cvauthor}}
                % \renewcommand{\name}{\cvauthor}
                % \name
                \ExtractInitials{\mycvauthor}
                \FirstInitial
                \SecondInitial
            }
    \end{textblock}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your intervention, I would like to know if you can propose  me some documentation or if you can give me more explanation about the answer to the problem. I mean internal work of tex.

Comment: @user13837279 That's a very broad request! Maybe https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-16#books-on-latex has some starting points